# Multiple Activities with multiple fragments in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-activity

I divided my app into three different activities: Authentication, Database, and Welcome screen.

For each package I Three activities and numerous fragments. My question is how to inflate each fragment to its corresponding activity? For example, Fragments google Authentication to Activity Auth.

Comment: Have you tried adding fragments dynamically using the fragment manager? If not let me know to post an answer.

Comment: Fragment transactions are handled in your activity using getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(currentFragment, destinationFragment).commit();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use fragment manager to dynamically switch between your fragments such as following:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                load(new fragment1()); //fragment1 is an already created fragment class name
            }
        });

public void load(Fragment f) #user defined function which loads fragment
{
    FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction=fm.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.f1,f); //f1 is an framelayout which will be replaced by fragment1
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

you can create a fragment class such as following

```
public class fragment1 extends Fragment {}
```

for more information on how to create and use fragments visit this website

https://guides.codepath.com/android/creating-and-using-fragments